# The inverse function theorem, problem with the proof

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I'm trying to go through proof of an inverse function theorem in multivariable analysis (described in Rudin's handbook) and I'm having problems understanding the part of the proof that deals with $f$ being 1-1, $f: U \rightarrow V$. How it is implied from the fact that $\varphi$ has a fixed point?

At the beginning I thought that it has something to do with the fact that $\varphi$ is contraction (hence it has fixed point) and if it is contraction then it is continous and if continous then it's 1-1 but now I'm not quite sure if this reasoning is correct.

Thanks in advance for any hints! [image]

Comment: yes it is correct! https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_fixed-point_theorem

Comment: but if it is contraction which solves $f$ being 1-1 why we care if $\varphi$ has a fixed point?

Comment: and how $\varphi$ being continous implies $f$ being continous?

Comment: for each $y$, you show that there is only one $x$ such that $f(x) = y$ (that is, $f$ is one-to-one in $U$). How do you show it? You use $\varphi$, and note that $f(x) = y$ if and only if $x$ is a fixed point for $\varphi$. Since $\varphi$ is a contraction, the fixed point exists and is **unique**, so there is only one $x$ such that $f(x) = y$ for every $y$.

Comment: No, it doesn't say that $f$ is continuous. It concludes that $f$ is $1-1$ since for any $y$ there is at most one $x$ such that $f(x)=y$. This is derived from the observation that $f(x)=y$ if and only if $x$ is a fixed point of $\phi$ and $\phi$ has only one fixed point.